# Convert Firebase Query Result

Tags: json, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Firebase Realtime Database using Javascript. Upon console-logging the result, I am stuck with what I presume is the query's metadata (pasted below).

> Xs {_repo: Ts, _path: Me, _queryParams: jt, _orderByCalled: true}...

I wish to interact with this data within Javascript. How can I convert this result to a readable format or access its individual children and values?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "",
authDomain: "",
databaseURL: "",
projectId: "",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "",
appId: "",
measurementId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);

var test = query(ref(db, "/Donors"), orderByValue(), 
limitToFirst(3))

console.log(test)
```

(I have removed config details because security rules have not yet been enforced.)

Here's how the database looks:

```
Donors  {

            John Smith

                         {
                            firstName: "John",
                            lastName: "Smith"
     
                          },
            Jack Smith

                         {
                            firstName: "Jack",
                            lastName: "Smith"
     
                          },
            Jeff Smith

                         {
                            firstName: "Jeff",
                            lastName: "Smith"
     
                          },
            Josh Smith

                         {
                            firstName: "Josh",
                            lastName: "Smith"
     
                          }
        }
```

Comment: To make it more likely someone can help, please edit your question to show the minimal code with which we can all reproduce that output. --- "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logging the `Query`, for which the output looks correct.

If you want to get the actual results and log those, you'll need to execute the query first for example by [listening to a value event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) on it or [getting the data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once).

Based on those links:

```
get(test).then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.key, child.val());
  });
});
```